# Integrable systems with Fano phase space?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, integrable-systems, fano-varieties

What are some known examples of finite-dimensional integrable systems with symplectic Fano phase space?

Here by integrable system we mean a symplectic manifold $(X, 
\omega)$ of dimension $2n$ with $n$ independent Poisson-commuting functions ('integrals').

The question is whether $X$ admits an almost complex structure $J$ compatible with the symplectic structure (i.e. $\omega(Jv, Ju)=\omega(u, v)$ and $\omega(u, Ju)>0$ for non-zero $u$) such that $\int_{A}c_1(TX)>0$ for homology classes $A \in H_2(X, \mathbb{Z})$ representable by $J$-holomorphic curves (I am quite ignorant of integrable systems with non-Kaehler phase space; that's why I used a symplectic definition without referring to Kaehler structure).

My motivation is largely geometric; namely such an integrable system would endow the phase space with a Lagrangian fibration (Liouville-Arnold).

https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09736 One example comes from compactified Ruijsenaars-Schneider systems whose phase space is $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2006 Another example is Gelfand - Zeytlin system whose phase space is flag variety $F_3$.

Some examples of non-K\"ahler symplectic Fano manifolds were constructed by Fine-Panov: https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3237